# REST API Endpoint .htaccess with Optional Fields (PHP)

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, rest

I am completely new to APIs. I created a UI for our web application (PHP environment) and wanted to develop an API. I used this resource to create an [REST API with PHP](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) and this resource for [best practices](https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards).

So far, I have the API working which would accept endpoints, such as:

- api/search.json
- api/search/log.json

The .json is added to meet the criteria of best practices and serves no functionality (other than possibly acting as a separator for my next task). I would like to include some optional fields. I was going to include these after the .json in this format:

- api/mandatory-term.json?optional=value
- api/mandatory-term.json?optional=value&anotheroptional=value

This was my attempt at an .htaccess solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/([^.?]+).json\?(.*)$ api/api.php?request=$1&fields=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/([^.?]+).json$ api/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the line that continues to fail:

```
RewriteRule ^api/([^.?]+).json\?(.*)$ api/api.php?request=$1&fields=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

If I remove the question mark (from the request and .htaccess), I can get the result I want in *fields* (except for an "&"; that'll break it). Would someone mind helping me understand how to capture that second field after a question mark while including ampersands? I'll most likely use the explode method to separate the capture into an array of optional arguments for the class methods.

Again, I completely new to this. I would love if someone could help me solve my .htaccess problem, but any other advice is welcome. I didn't have the choice of what environment to implement this in. I would have preferred to have done this with J2EE but... no such luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were close but you can't match a query string in the `pattern` of the rewriterule. You need to match the querystring or use QSA. I modified the rules a bit. 
Give this a try.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^api/([^.?]+)\.json$ api/api.php?request=$1&fields=%1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^api/([^.?]+)\.json$ api/api.php?request=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that it will take the entire querystring in the request and add it to the `fields` var as you requested.

You could just also use the QSA flag to append the query string added to the rewrite.